# Python: using X and Y values to draw a picture

Tags: python, numpy, module, scipy

I have a series of methods that take an image 89x22 pixels (although the size, theoretically, is irrelevant) and fits a curve to each row of pixels to find the location of the most significant signal. At the end, I have a list of Y-values, one for each row of pixels, and a list of X-values, the location of the most significant peak for each row.

I would like to test different types of curves to see which models the data better, and in order to do so, I would like to be able to print out a new image, also 89x22 pixels, with the location of the most significant peak marked with a single red pixel for each line. A have attached an input example and a (poorly drawn) example of what I expect a good output to look like:

[image: input image] [image: output image]

Any suggestions on which modules to start looking in?

```
class image :

    def importImage (self) :
        """Open an image and sort all pixel values into a list of lists"""
        from PIL import Image               #imports Image from PIL library

        im = Image.open("testTop.tif")      #open the file
        size = im.size                      #size object is a tuple with the pixel width and pixel height
        width = size[0]                     #defines width object as the image width in pixels
        height = size[1]                    #defines the height object as the image height in pixels

        allPixels = list(im.getdata())      #makes a list of all pixels values
        pixelList = [allPixels[width*i : width * (i+1)] for i in range(height)]     #takes mega-list and makes a list of lists by row
        return(pixelList)                   #returns list of lists

    def fitCurves (self) :
        """
        Iterate through a list of lists and fit a curve to each list of integers. 
        Append the position of the list and the location of the vertex to a growing list.
        """
        from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
        import numpy as np
        from matplotlib import pyplot as pp
        from scipy.misc import factorial

        image = self.importImage()
        xList = []
        yList = []
        position = 0

        for row in image :
            #Gaussian fit equations kindly provided by user mcwitt
            x = np.arange(len(row))
            ffunc = lambda x, a, x0, s: a*np.exp(-0.5*(x-x0)**2/s**2)   # define function to fit
            p, _ = curve_fit(ffunc, x, row, p0=[100,5,2])           # fit with initial guess a=100, x0=5, s=2
            x0 = p[1]
            yList.append(position)
            position = position + 1
            xList.append(x0)
        print(yList)
        print(xList)

newImage = image()
newImage.fitCurves()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mabye:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import ndimage
from scipy import optimize
%matplotlib inline

# just a gaussian (copy paste from lmfit, another great package)
def my_gaussian(p,x):
    amp = p[0]
    cen = p[1]
    wid = p[2]
    return amp * np.exp(-(x-cen)**2 /wid)

# I do like to write a cost function separately. For the leastsquare algorithm it should return a vector.
def my_cost(p,data):
    return data - my_gaussian(p,data)

# i load the image and generate the x values
image = ndimage.imread('2d_gaussian.png',flatten=True)
x = np.arange(image.shape[1])
popt = []

# enumerate is a convenient way to loop over an iterable and keep track of the index.
y = []
for index,data in enumerate(image):
    ''' this is the trick to make the algorithm robust. 
    I do plug the index of the maximum value of the current row as
    initial guess for the center. Maybe it would be enough to do
    just that and the fit is unnecessary. Haven`t checked that.
    '''
    max_index = np.argmax(data)
    # initial guess.
    x0 = [1.,max_index,10]
    # call to the solver
    p,_ = optimize.leastsq(my_cost, x0, args = data)
    popt.append(p)
    y.append(index)
''' 
I do transpose the data.
As a consequence the values are stored row, not columnwise.
It is often easier to store the reusults inside a loop and 
convert the data later into a numpy array.
'''
gaussian_hat = np.array(popt).T
# without the transpose, it would be center = gaussian_hat[:,1]
center = gaussian_hat[1]
y = np.array(y)

''' i do like to use an axis handle for the plot. 
Not necessary, but gives me the opportunity to add new axis if necessary.
'''
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.imshow(image)
# since it is just a plot, I can plot the x, y coordinates
ax.plot(center,y,'k-')

# fitt of a 3th order polynomial
poly = np.polyfit(y,center,3)
# evaluation at points y
x_hat = np.polyval(poly,y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.imshow(image)
ax.plot(x_hat,y,'k-')
plt.savefig('2d_gaussian_fit.png')
```

[image: Without polynomial fit]

[image: with polynomial fit]

Comment: That is amazingly cool! Is there any way that you could add a tad bit of inline comments?  I'm very interested in learning more about this, but not all of the code is intuitive. If not, thank you anyway!

Comment: keep in mind that colours can be misleading. The gradient may not be that sharp as the colours would suppose. Cubehelix may be a better option `cmap = plt.cm.cubehelix` as argument to imshow.

Comment: Can you explain why the starting estimate for the least squares minimization is a list of three numbers?  I see how providing the maximum value (as the initial estimate for the center of the curve) is advantageous but I don't understand how always passing in 1 and 10 is advantageous. If maxIndex estimates the center of the curve, do 1 and 10 estimate the height and width of the curve?  Yes, I'm still working on understanding this code :)

Comment: the parameters are amplitude, center and width of the peak. The amp and wid parameter depend on your data and either you know good estimates in beforehand or you might try cross correlation.